# Help with First Order Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have difficulty to solve the following problem:
"Solve The Cauchy Problem:
[image]

in the domain of x>0 ,y>0.
Does the equation have a single solution around the beginning curve?
if there is find u(x,y).
my answer
in the domain x>0,y>0 u is positive.so we can divide by u.
the rest of my calculations:

[image]

the official answer is :
u(x,y)=x^2+y^2

I don't understand what is wrong my solution.
thank's :)

Comment: please use latex

Comment: The question will be a lot more well received if you will use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I have a mistake when I multiplied by two and when I plug-in A and B.
mathjax &RHowe Thanks for the advice I will try that next time:)

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake:
if plug $A(s)$ and $B(s)$ Wrong
and I multiplied by 2 wrong
$(e^t)^2=e^{2t} $